# How to find an element inside an element and an attribute with a CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, data-mining

How do i find the value from the element inside an element

```
<div style="width: 15%" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" role="button" data-original-title="" title="" data-content="<i>15%</i><b>Web Design</b>" class="grid custom_popover"></div>
```

How to extract the 15 from this line`data-content="<i>15%</i><b>Web Design</b>"`
The selector is the CSS selector.

I have used this `div[data-content*="Web Design"]::attr(data-content)`

which gives me this result `10%Web Design`

But how to get this result `10%`

Comment: CSS selectors are used to select elements, not their attributes. You'd need something more than CSS...

Comment: Try it  with javascript, etc..